# How do I get from Element type to double type in Dart?

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:html';


main() {
  var ba = new BankAccount( "My Name", '3810-482974-3847', 10000000000.0);
  var amount = querySelector("#amount");
  //I need something here to take Element amount, and make it a String amount.
  double.parse(amount);
  querySelector("#dep").onClick.listen( (e) => ba.deposit(amount) );
  querySelector("#with").onClick.listen( (e) => ba.withdraw(amount) );
}



class BankAccount {
  String owner, number;
  double balance;
  // Constructor:
  BankAccount(this.owner, this.number, this.balance);
  // Methods:
  deposit(double amount) => balance += amount;
  withdraw(double amount) => balance -= amount;
}
```

Hello people! I just got into dart programming, and I have been playing around with web application building. It is obviously very rudimentary and still in alpha development, however I need help with getting from an element(Pulled off of attached HTML from "Number" input) to a String, int, or even a double. My current goal is to have a webpage that has two buttons and a number input. The number input comes in as amount, and the buttons trigger deposit or withdraw. The overall balance is predetermined in the definition of "ba".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#amount` is an `<input type="number">` then you can use

```
amount = (querySelector("#amount") as NumberInputElement).valueAsNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

An HTML Input Element has a `value`, so if `#amount` is an input element use

```
double.parse(querySelector('#amount').value);
```